# Swift ios only hide UIView or also hide elements inside UIView

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiview

In one viewcontroller I have a few `UIViews` that constain some text labels and buttons. Depending on what data I receive from my API I either hide some of the `UIViews` or populate them with data.

My question now is, can I just hide the `UIView` or must I also hide all of the elements that are nested inside the `UIView` ?

Eg:

```
myView.hidden = true
myView.userinteractionsEnabled = false
```

vs

```
myView.hidden = true
myView.userinteractionsEnabled = false

// And some stuff inside/nested myView
myButton.hidden = true
myButton.userinteractionsEnabled = false
myLabel.hidden = true
```

Comment: hiding view will hide subviews inside...

Comment: @sanmanborate Yea I can see that it gets hidden, but I was not clear before. I wonder if the subViews/buttons inside the parrent view still can be active and therefore needs to me set as disabled/hidden

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It hides the subviews too.

You can test this easily enough in a Playground:

```
import UIKit

var v = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0,0, 600, 600))
v.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()

var subv = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(100,100, 200, 200))
subv.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()

var subv2 = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(10,10, 50, 50))
subv2.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

subv.addSubview(subv2)


v.addSubview(subv)

subv.hidden = true
v
```

Here is the result:

[image: Subviews in a playground]

Comment: Yea I can see that it gets hidden, but I was not clear before. I wonder if the subViews/buttons inside the parrent view still can be active and therefore needs to me set as disabled/hidden

Answer (score 1):

Hide the view that the other views are inside of. Hiding a view will also hide its subviews.

Comment: Yea I can see that it gets hidden, but I was not clear before. I wonder if the subViews/buttons inside the parrent view still can be active and therefore needs to me set as disabled/hidden

Comment: I don't believe they have to be hidden as well. They will be disabled if the parent view is hidden

Answer (score 0):

You just have to hide only the parent view.

Comment: Yea I can see that it gets hidden, but I was not clear before. I wonder if the subViews/buttons inside the parrent view still can be active and therefore needs to me set as disabled/hidden